# How can I fix this function

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I've been working on a school assignment using Haskell and keep getting the same parse-errors over and over again. I've been looking online and have gotten no solutions to my problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is the function...

```
maxGaussNorm :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt
maxGaussNorm [] = (0,0)
maxGaussNorm gs = maxAux (tail gs) (head gs)

maxAux :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt -> GaussianInt
maxAux gs m 
      | gs == [] = m
      | (gaussNorm (head gs)) <= (gaussNorm m) = maxAux (tail gs) m
      | (gaussNorm (head gs)) > (gaussNorm m) = maxAux (tail gs) (head gs)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VdNb5tAEL3zK0Y54dgo4FutOlKUL6VSUqntLUqqDazxJuxCYWkWVf3t7syCDXacpGpwpHKBfZ6vfW9mwXNWPPAkWSx@eXBUFCJWkisNYwc8uGKST@ATL3Sl4KvOxQOhJ0wjOvYPAv9g7AcfEPvtyDQqE95E@D6GxznPueNIFooIJhPrreJmPYW9gqLd7zmOrjIO56xER6YuMPMUXLzxmOej5j5wHCzOe@tFtceU6AtnCS16iXjCizAXmRapmsCp0TkLdQF6ziHHNPCTJSWHdGaRuNkmiHpj5D/LU2l/5D9KRlHADCsxQm9d5qoAY@ld1U1cdtnyDqFhqWPjmlE1QCJNz8RdSBa/A3EC0wjF8urt7FUte1T8a@xZmyV7ldMvfceput8Neydc81wKxWv@QkxUxjilxBx7mbfNHze7z6tESyHtYAuFnWXHLqZJNiMPuawPA8DLINj2aWyxaolZ9uOee/YoinZDOgZGuh/TJxQimsYcyc1HwFS04pLonmFfJ1sVuWMFj1Cw2bLdVx3tusYfmmAwcit/WAWDQSsI1vCyHlvlIa/YhzgghTA4DIHCA8bHR8rQVcxfl8yv0WAdDWol/XUpa9sqWEeDnhW@LBO9G4kpssgSwd9P6H1k1kMi9ysS3NDdyrNf@V3hqbJ/UN66daVfSweb@f6rNrhKc/kuxyslev5kbeRV69La87Y@Ws3tmKbsdtyqaSO@8mqyNvZM7fA9sLHcDquI9MerZOZ8t9SeCRXVrGIuIUvZcqpow0IhzYko7IBr9tBIoBoJ6HnOWVTLQXb1JIapzFiOxkLjjD5xUdxoa11/YFBs8khQ5wKlC3n9asQPOAR0U0kB0bIPoifjzrIsTzNB79wtTYGfxx0mSenrjtQ3m6O6ZhwXqHmzn0tmwNVMoPLFAFy7c3yy49UxeSX@ZroNb0woLUYXZZ/C9Q3W0AGXxa0qgI/TFgX5XMUvhjj8mwjtnu3VV6N/I5mPcXKLvtq8t3Hx4KxUoZ2WermqFa5KecfzBr5QWamb51OT8VBjm34udYsehaXGQ6OL9f6XKqS6AtvyzmLxBw)

Comment: *What* parse errors are you getting? And how is `GaussianInt` defined?

Comment: GaussianInt is defined as type GaussianInt = (Integer,Integer), the error that I keep getting is Assign_2.hs:90:18: error:
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'      
   |
90 |         gs == [] = m
   |                  ^

Comment: Did you make sure not to have mixed tabs and spaces for indentation?

Comment: I have been only using tabs, Ill try with spaces

Comment: Is this the whole file? This section of code is not giving parse errors. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Pzexwj2xtLjYL78oV8HKSiEazMtMzPPMK4lV0LVTQOJzoSiOjlWwVdAw0DHQRBVPLwaKA0UcSysUNEoSM3OAIpoKGhmpiSkgFhcXVI6AZVjsBukCmp6rwKUABjVgu2whLsmFC2qkw90Ct1VTwcYWWSJXE5sjCZlhR9gIhD///wcA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I still am getting the same error

Comment: This isnt the whole code, but its the only part that has been getting errors

Comment: @JestynStrik No, tabs should work fine as well, you just need to avoid mixing them with spaces which can lead to non-obvious errors, so this was just my first guess on correct-looking code. As Potato44 said, please post a [mcve]

Comment: The error message in your comment earlier says it is happening on line 90. Can you post whatever is is on line 90 along with the few lines of context either side of it?

Comment: line 90 is this      | gs == [] = m       this is supposed to return the head of the original list if the list is only one value long

Comment: I've filled in some dummy definitions to make your code work: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU9BCoMwELznFXNMwIJnaYSeSi/9gHgIbVCpSUsSwUL/nq5WrILgXjY7O5mZrZV/6LaN0aj@rDrvr09nkGUoxqlR9mJDiUOOxcxW5KKEBE@TVKzxyhNOyKnrwYNqWkIEeK3VfXgxNu12zDa8h1@kbsAw1mf0kr8kZgZ5NWeZXQWOcrkwYivknka@L7G4cyijGks0p0PnLDih4f3SqzspFzVdaZdMnVh/G4nb0/qANMYv "Haskell – Try It Online"). I haven't touched your part of the code in any way but copy and paste, so the error is definitely elsewhere.

Comment: I opened the program into the online tester, how can I send you the link?

Comment: @Potato44 i put the hyperlink in the top, hopefully you could access it

Comment: @JestynStrik Well in the code by the link there is not even a function `maxAux`. There is however a function `maxGaussNorm` with a subfunction `compareMax` and it needs a `where` keyword and some guards to fix its syntax.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov could you explain how i can express the function using where and the guards?

Comment: Please ask new questions in a new post.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted in the link is different from what you have posted in the question body.

Here is your code that actually has parse errors

```
maxGaussNorm :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt
maxGaussNorm gs = compareMax (tail gs) (head gs)
    compareMax :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt -> GaussianInt
    compareMax gs m
        gs == [] = m
        gaussNorm(head gs) <= gaussNorm m = compareMax (tail gs) m
        gaussNorm(head gs) > gaussNorm m = compareMax (tail gs) (head gs)
```

There are two things wrong with this, missing the pipe character `|` on the guards, 
and you forgot to include a `where` keyword before the definition of `compareMax`.

Here is the code with these parse error fixed

```
maxGaussNorm :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt
maxGaussNorm gs = compareMax (tail gs) (head gs)
  where
    compareMax :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt -> GaussianInt
    compareMax gs m
       | gs == [] = m
       | gaussNorm(head gs) <= gaussNorm m = compareMax (tail gs) m
       | gaussNorm(head gs) > gaussNorm m = compareMax (tail gs) (head gs)
```

The code you originally posted with the question also is a solution to the parse errors by rewriting the helper function as a top level function and including the pipes on the guards

```
maxGaussNorm :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt
maxGaussNorm [] = (0,0)
maxGaussNorm gs = maxAux (tail gs) (head gs)

maxAux :: [GaussianInt] -> GaussianInt -> GaussianInt
maxAux gs m 
      | gs == [] = m
      | (gaussNorm (head gs)) <= (gaussNorm m) = maxAux (tail gs) m
      | (gaussNorm (head gs)) > (gaussNorm m) = maxAux (tail gs) (head gs)
```

This implementation is also slightly different in that it handles empty lists instead of erroring.